# sed multiline pygmentize

Tags: sed, command-line-interface

I would like to take the html piece and pass it to pygmentize to colorize it accordingly. I'm wondering how I could use sed or some other cli tool to get that accomplished.

I tried a bunch of sed one-liners and tried to use the following SO questions:

- [Sed multiline replacement question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350800/sed-multiline-replacement-question)
- [Using or in multiline sed replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826049/using-or-in-multiline-sed-replacement)
- [sed or awk multiline replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377092/sed-or-awk-multiline-replace)

I have the following log:

```
2012-03-26 18:04:27,385 9372 [main] ERROR web.commons.exception.ServiceInvocationException  - 
Response from server cannot be decoded to JSON, responsePayload = <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing jetty-url. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</body>
</html>

org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@369133f6; line: 1, column: 2]
```

**UPDATE** I'm adding this to a longer command:

```
mvn -U test | (while read line; do echo ${line} | sed -e "s/.*ERROR.*/`echo -e '\e[91m&\e[0m'`/g" -e "s/.*\(WARN|INFO\).*/`echo -e '\e[93m&\e[0m'`/g"; done)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this as part of a longer command:

```
mvn -U test | (while read line; do echo ${line} | sed -e "s/.*ERROR.*/`echo -e '\e[91m&\e[0m'`/g" -e "s/.*\(WARN|INFO\).*/`echo -e '\e[93m&\e[0m'`/g"; done)
```

Answer (score 2):

> cat log | awk '/<html>/,/<\/html>/'

Should do it.

To remove the "crap" before the first html tag, get sed to put the html tag on it's own line.

> cat log | sed 's/<html>/\n<html>/' | awk '/<html>/,/<\/html>/'

Comment: you'll need to escape the '/' in the END pattern. Also, given the user's sample input, I think your solution will include the non-html text the precedes the opening `<html>` that looks to be on the same line. Good luck to all.

Comment: Hmm. thats odd. On the preview the escape shows. on the final answer, it doesn't!

Comment: Hey this cool but still has the first line's input and it's going to be part of a longer command. This might be overkill though your answer is still very helpful. I might create a python program to provide some help if it's too much.

Comment: I'll edit it to handle the start bit. Standby (good fun for a Tuesday morning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

TXR:

For illustration purposes, we replace `pygmentize` with a command that replaces every letter in the HTML with X.

```
@;; replace with .e.g. pygmentize
@(bind filter "tr [A-Za-z] X")
@date @time @pid [@function] @error_1
@error_2 <html>
@(collect)
@stuff
@(last)
</html>
@(end)

@error_3
@(output)
@date @time @pid [@function] @error_1
@error_2
@(end)
@(output `!@filter`)
<html>
@{stuff "\n"}
</html>
@(end)
@(output)
@error_3
@(end)
```

Test run:

```
$ txr  log.txr  log.txt
2012-03-26 18:04:27,385 9372 [main] ERROR web.commons.exception.ServiceInvocationException  -
Response from server cannot be decoded to JSON, responsePayload =
<XXXX>
<XXXX>
<XXXX XXXX-XXXXX="XXXXXXX-XXXX" XXXXXXX="XXXX/XXXX; XXXXXXX=XXX-8859-1"/>
<XXXXX>XXXXX 404 XXX XXXXX</XXXXX>
</XXXX>
<XXXX><X2>XXXX XXXXX 404</X2>
<X>XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX-XXX. XXXXXX:
<XXX>    XXX XXXXX</XXX></X><XX /><X><XXXXX>XXXXXXX XX XXXXX://</XXXXX></X><XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>
<XX/>

</XXXX>
</XXXX>
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```